# Div will not maintain width in Safari on an iPad

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

So i have a ridiculous problem, that ought to be obvious and simple yet I can't seem to find out what the problem is.

I have a div on a page that uses bootstrap.

The code for that div is as follows:-

```
    .appSection{
    background-color: #000000;
    padding:20px;
    border:1px solid #67c1dd;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 450px;
}
```

Its a child of a div wrapper col-md-12.

This display fine in most browsers I've used; however, when the div does not contain much content or text at the head of the div, on the iPad the div collapses as shown in the right side of the attached image. Sometimes it can literally be collapsed almost completely to the right of the underlying menu.

Any clues?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You haven't given us enough information to go off. If we could see a sample of you html and css that would be great.

If you are reviewing it on iPad in portrait, then your "col-md-12" class on the parent div is not being applied, as that starts at 992px. That is probably 'part' of your problem. **It's not the root cause though**. but with nothing else to go on, try changing it to "col-xs-12" and see if that fixes it.

Comment: I've changed the media queries on bootstrap to invoke at different resolutions. However, sufficed to say I know that col-md-12 is being applied because the navigation "Application Menu" changes to the style you can see in the image when the col-md-12 class is applied. I can provide a link where someone can see the problem, but I would prefer to do that privately.

Comment: That's not the point of stack overflow. Create a codepen that replicates your issue and reference it or add the code snippets here so we can replicate your issue.

Answer (score -1):

I've found the problem.

I had this meta tag at the top of my page, when I removed it, the problem was resolved:-

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
```

Comment: That's not the answer to your problem. Your page won't work responsively without the viewport meta tag.